# Docker on Windows without Docker Desktop volume mounting

Tags: docker, docker-volume, wsl-2

My goal is to use the docker-cli in Windows (docker.exe), but using Linux containers, **without** the installation of Docker Desktop. I mainly followed these instructions to install Ubuntu 20.04-LTS using WSL2 and prepare everything that dockerd is running inside this instance. (https://dev.to/_nicolas_louis_/how-to-run-docker-on-windows-without-docker-desktop-hik)

I currently start dockerd with "-H tcp://127.0.0.1" and it does work, I can pull images, run containers, build images etc. from a Windows terminal, my environment contains DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375

What does not work is binding or mounting volumes to local directories, which used to work, when Docker Desktop was installed.

For example trying to run jboss/keycloak mounting */opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data* to some local path gives me:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data
```

which - again - used to work with Docker Desktop, so I do not assume an error in my call.

Can anyone help me getting this to work?

Comment: How are you mounting the directories? can you provide an example? The daemon is running in wsl so probably you need to specify paths in the wsl subsistem

Comment: My call contains: -v D:\localPath\subPath:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data . I will comment with more detail in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your docker daemon is running in WSL and you are just connecting to it with de docker command on Windows.

This means that every docker command is actually executed on the WSL subsystem and paths should be specified accordingly.

In particular you should specify paths in WSL, usually your `C:/` drive is mounted in WSL under `\mnt\c`.

I would suggest trying to modifying your run command with those paths, so something like:

```sh
docker run -v C:\test\folder:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data ...
```

Would become:

```sh
docker run -v /mnt/c/test/folder:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data ...
```

Make sure you pay attention to the slashes: in WSL you need a foreward slash (`/`) whereas windows does not really care.

Comment: Call me stupid, but I think, this was one of my many attempts to get this working. But since I had no success, I went on. Maybe I did another mistake. It works now. But please - why did Windows paths work with Docker Desktop before? Isn't the deamon running inside wsl in any case? Is there a way to make Windows paths work in my current scenario?

Comment: If you use Docker Desktop the daemon is actually running in Windows this is why it was working before. Unfortunately if you want to run docker from WSL (not using Docker Desktop) this will be the only way to use volumes. Also please mark the answare as correct if it is working :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! So, the Windows deamon is part of the product "Docker Desktop" then? When I want to stay without Docker Desktop, I need the deamon inside wsl?

Comment: Exactly, this is very unfortunate but currently only linux has a standalone daemon, Windows and MacOS have to install Docker Desktop to get a native daemon.