# use docker build in VS2022 without Docker Desktop: invalid volume specification

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2022, wsl-2

docker CLI is setup manually with docker context to WSL2 exposing dockerd to tcp/2375

VisualStudio build fails with e.g.:

Error   CTC1003 Visual Studio container tools require Docker to be running.

in the output details there multiple volume mounting failing:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro'
```

tried in CLI manually with different escaping slashes etc. failing as well

```
docker run -v c:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro container
```

whereas using default mnt points from WSL works fine

```
 docker run --rm -it -v \mnt\c\Users\user\x:/home/user/x:ro ubuntu
```

like mentioned in [Docker on Windows without Docker Desktop volume mounting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71126797/docker-on-windows-without-docker-desktop-volume-mounting) but I have no choice as VS2022 is issuing the commands probably not configurable.

Initionally to get to the point where I stuck with VS2022, I somehow had to create a Windows local group `docker-user` upfront so I guess it's some magic built into Docker Desktop but not in normal CLI?

> docker info:
> Client:  Version:    24.0.7  Context:    wsl  Debug Mode: false
>
> Server:  Containers: 2   Running: 1   Paused: 0   Stopped: 1  Images:
> 10  Server Version: 25.0.0

docker CLI is setup manually with docker context to WSL2 exposing dockerd to tcp/2375

visual studio fails with e.g.:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro'.
```

tried manually with different escaping slashes etc.

```
docker run -v c:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro container
```

whereas

```
 docker run --rm -it -v \mnt\c\Users\user\x:/home/user/x:ro ubuntu
```

just runs fine.

I somehow had to create a Windows local group upfront so I guess it's some magic built into Docker Desktop but not in normal CLI?

> docker info:
> Client:  Version:    24.0.7  / tested 25.0.1 as well
> Server:  Server Version: 25.0.0

also tried to run VS2022 with Admin permissions, but no difference.

the `docker build` before the `docker runs` just runs fine!

Comment: "Docker for Desktop is not just a daemon+cli and a fancy GUI. There are in fact many proprietary components in that package."
 https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/pr5yn4/windows_paths_format_is_not_recognized_by_docker/